# Splitting a data frame to create new columns

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns for "Count","Transect Number","Data", and "Year". My goal is to split up the data frame by Transect, then again by Year, and create a new data frame with a column for "Transect", and then the appropriate data per Year in the following columns.

To build a dummy data frame:

```
Count1<-1:27
Count2<-1:30
Count3<-1:25
T1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
T2<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
T3<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
Data1<-c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,3,2)
Data2<-c(1,2,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,2,4,3,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,1,4,5,4,3,2)
Data3<-c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,3,2,3,4)
Year1<-c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016)
Year2<-c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016)
Year3<-c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016)




DF1<-data.frame(Count1,T1,Data1,Year1)
colnames(DF1)<-c("Count","Transect","Data","Year")
DF2<-data.frame(Count2,T2,Data2,Year2)
colnames(DF2)<-c("Count","Transect","Data","Year")
DF3<-data.frame(Count3,T3,Data3,Year3)
colnames(DF3)<-c("Count","Transect","Data","Year")


All<-rbind(DF1,DF2,DF3)
```

Once I have the data frame, my thought was to split up the data by transect since this will be a permanent aspect of my ongoing data set.

```
#Step 1-Break down by T
Trans1<-All[All$Transect==1,]
Trans2<-All[All$Transect==2,]
Trans3<-All[All$Transect==3,]
Trans4<-All[All$Transect==4,]
Trans5<-All[All$Transect==5,]
```

But I'm a little less clear on the next step. I need to pull out data from the "Data" column organized by year. Something along the lines of further breaking down the data like so:

```
Trans1_Year1<-Trans1[Trans1$Year==2014,]
Trans2_Year1<-Trans2[Trans2$Year==2014,]
Trans3_Year1<-Trans3[Trans3$Year==2014,]
Trans4_Year1<-Trans4[Trans4$Year==2014,]
Trans5_Year1<-Trans5[Trans5$Year==2014,]
```

or even using split

```
ByYear1<-split(Trans1,Trans1$Year)
```

But I would prefer to avoid writing out the code as above as I hope to add new data every year as this data set progresses. And I'd like the code to be able to accommodate new "Year" data as it is added, as opposed to writing out new lines of code every year.

Once I have the data set up like so, I'd like to create a second data frame with columns for each year. One problem is that the each year contains differing numbers of rows, which has been an issue for me. But my final result would have columns:

```
 "Transect", "Data 2014", "Data 2015", "Data 2016"
```

Since each year has can have different numbers of rows within a transect, I'd like to leave NA's at the end of each Transect section when the number of rows per individual transect differ between years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are basically trying to convert your data into a semi-wide format, with columns for years, rather than keeping it in the "long" format.

If this is the case, you're better off adding a secondary index column that shows the repeated combination of "Transect" and "Year".

This can easily be done with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. "splitstackshape" also loads "data.table", from which you could then use `dcast.data.table` to get a wide format.

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(getanID(All, c("Transect", "Year")), 
                 Transect + .id ~ Year, value.var = "Data")
#     Transect .id 2014 2015 2016
#  1:        1   1    1    2    3
#  2:        1   2    2    1    4
#  3:        1   3    3    2    5
#  4:        1   4    1    2    4
#  5:        1   5    2    4    5
#  6:        1   6    3    3    6
#  7:        1   7    1    4    4
#  8:        1   8    2    5    4
#  9:        1   9    3    4    3
# 10:        1  10   NA   NA    4
# 11:        2   1    2    3    4
# 12:        2   2    1    4    3
# 13:        2   3    2    3    2
# 14:        2   4    2    2    3
# 15:        2   5    1    3    2
# 16:        2   6    4    4    1
# 17:        2   7    4    3    4
# 18:        2   8    5    3    3
# 19:        2   9    4    2    2
# 20:        2  10   NA   NA    3
# 21:        3   1    3    2    3
# 22:        3   2    4    1    3
# 23:        3   3    3    2    2
# 24:        3   4    3    3    5
# 25:        3   5    2    2    4
# 26:        3   6    1    3    3
# 27:        3   7    3    3    2
# 28:        3   8    3    4    4
# 29:        3   9    3    5   NA
#     Transect .id 2014 2015 2016
```

Then, if you really want to split on the "Transect" column you can go ahead and use `split`, but since you now have a "data.table" it would be better to stick with that and take advantage of its many convenient features, including those related to subsetting and aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forcing your data into a format it does not have naturally. There are a lot of processing advantages to leaving it in "long" format. Have a look at this article if you have not seen it yet, it is a classic.

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12

Comment: I agree that the long format is usually better, and I'll keep it in the long format for making plots based on this data. But for various reasons, I'd like to have my data set up as mentioned above.

Comment: So would it not make more sense to keep it in long format for storage, and then just make it into a wide table with code when you need to? Or is that your intention?

Comment: @MikeWise, it sounds like they already have the data in a long format and just need to do some additional work on it. (So in other words, yes, it sounds like that's their intention.)